# split filter callback function out

Tags: javascript, function, callback

```
arr.filter(filterCallback(this, newValue));

function filterCallback(this, newValue){
   return this !== newValue;
}
```

Above code doesn't work, not sure what's wrong. this is working before I try to split the function out.

```
arr.filter(function(val){
    return val !== newValue;
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Are you trying to call `filterCallback` as `.filter()` callback? What is purpose of `this` as parameter at `filterCallback(this, newValue)`?

Comment: @SharathBangera make filter no inner function.

Comment: bind `newValue` as `thisArg`.....  `arr.filter(filterCallback.bind(newValue));

function filterCallback(value){
   return value !== this;
}`

Comment: Why do you use `this` instead of `val`? And why would `newVal` suddenly become a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to call `filterCallback` with parameter, and receives current element of `.filter()` `callback` to compare values. You can also set `this` of `filterCallback()` call as first parameter passed to `.bind()`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];

var not = {n:3};

var res = arr.filter(filterCallback.bind(not));

function filterCallback(el){
    return this.n !== el;
}

console.log(res); // [1, 2]
```

Comment: can not be a string?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:-

```
arr.filter(filterCallback);

function filterCallback(){
   return newValue;
}
```

Check  snippet

```js
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
    return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages.filter(checkAdult);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get every element in the array that has a value of 18 or more.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```